# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException on CAS Services

Tags: java, ssl, https, single-sign-on, cas

Short story, my boss want to use single login for many application we made and i try CAS for this need.

I'm trying to install CAS as my SSO. i generate jks file from keytool in java bin. login and logout works fine until i want to try add some services.

```
https://localhost:8443/cas/services/j_acegi_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-2-Ts4EoUqKfeGOGGi1XbXq-cas01.example.org
```

This Error will come out :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:341)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:305)
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:50)
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:207)
```

So i google and try this thing but still failed :

First thing i run this command and it success :

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\Users\User\Documents\keystore.jks -keysize 2048
keytool -certreq -alias localhost -keystore C:\Users\User\Documents\keystore.jks -file C:\Users\User\Documents\localhost.csr
```

import jks file to java

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias localhost -keystore "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -file "D:\apache tomcat 6\bin\keystore.jks"
```

but an error come out :

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

also try generate x509 file

```
openssl x509 -in "C:\Users\User\Documents\localhost.csr" -out "C:\Users\User\Documents\localhost.der" -outform DER
```

but this error come out :

```
unable to load certificate
24516:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_li
b.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Please advice if any solution i can try?

PS : using tomcat 6 on windows 8 64 bit. (that's why i always use my document folder, because its not working if i use somewhere else)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi i solve this my self at last...

maybe someone else need this..

1. i run the application with https with jks file i export.
2. view certificates with browser.
3. Export it and save into .cer file
4. import it with java keytool.

this is the command :

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias localhost -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -file "D:/apache tomcat 6/bin/daniel2.cer"
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Could you please brief the steps you followed. I am bit confused as even I am also facing this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it according your steps but with one more step.
After command

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\Users\User\Documents\keystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

it asks for your last and first name. The first and last name must be the **host name** of your server and cannot be an IP address. I entered my real first an last name and it was incorrect.